Christian Accountability for Actions Done in Fight or Flight
Christians, when our brain goes into "fight or flight" mode are we held to the same accountability for our actions as when we are in our normal meditative state?

God has given you control over your actions even in fight or flight mode, hardly emotion rules over the brain because to get angry is a sin

As noted in another answer, God knows and takes into account the motives in our hearts, our understanding of the situation, extenuating circumstances, etc. In Romans 2, Paul talks about how our conscience will both defend and accuse us before God.
Within the Mosaic Law, God required that the Jews establish towns which those who accidentally killed someone could flee to and report the situation to the congregation. The avenger of blood could not touch him - instead he would be put on trial. If he was found guilty by the witness of at least 2 witnesses he would be put to death. But if it was found that it was accidental then he would live in that town until the death of the High Priest. (Numbers 35)

What about in Hebrews where it says that if we sin willfully after having received the knowledge of the truth, there remaineth no more sacrifice for sins? What qualifies as having received the knowledge of truth? What about original sin?

Those are each different topics that probably deserve their own thread. However as Paul teaches in 1 Corinthians 15 (i believe it was) flesh cannot inherit the kingdom. Ultimately we will be remade, a new creation. Our current bodies are as soil, and the Word a seed. While we must strive for perfection, and persevere in our pursuit of the good - we will not lose our salvation for tripping up here and there. Knowledge of the truth = the Gospel. And I don’t believe in the doctrine of Original Sin myself.

okay that makes sense thanks!

In hebrews where it says if we are in full knowledge of the truth of God and we still decide to sin it will not be forgiven. I know you say there is no such thing as original sin which I agree with but if we werent born with original sin does that mean we were born knowing the truth of God and therefore we were never allowed to sin in the first place? That would kind of make it pointless what Jesus did for us right?

@CodyRutscher if you manage to live without sin, then you don’t need forgiveness. While technically possible, we are born of the flesh and the desires of the flesh run contrary to the will of God. Not that any natural desire is wrong - they are even a blessing - but they must not become our master. And no - sinlessness is not the same as knowing the truth of God - however if you manage to live without sun then chances are it’s because you have found it

@RyanPierceWilliams You do not believe in the doctrine of original sin how do you account for you being a sinner? Also, how do you reconcile your position with what the Apostle Paul stated at Romans 5:12, "Therefore, just as sin came into the world through one man/Adam, and death  through sin, and so death spread to all men because ALL SINNED," You also said, "if you manage to live without sin, then you don’t need forgiveness. While technically possible," No, it is impossible for a person to live a sinless life in these body's of flesh. Rom. 3:23, 6;23 Only Jesus was sinless because He is God.

@Mr.Bond I am a sinner because I have chosen of my own volition to sin - no different than Adam and Eve. Death is a consequence of Adam and Eve’s sin that we share - but that is a different thing from sharing moral responsibility for their sin. We are simply born mortal. Hence we still die even after we acquire forgiveness through Christ.

If that is true did you choose to sign as a baby? Psalm 51:5, NASB. "Behold, I was brought forth in iniquity,  And in sin my mother conceived." NET, Look, I was guilty of sin from birth, a sinner the moment my mother conceived me." Do you need more verses? John 14:4, "Who can make a clean thing come from an unclean? No one!" I rest my case.

A poetic line from Psalms does not establish your case, nor does the passage in John support your position at all. Whilst punishment for sin may extend across generations that is a very different thing from having personal, moral responsibility for that sin.

@Mr.Bond by your logic Christ could not be sinless since he was born to sinful man. Mary was a sinner. And to claim that she must not have been creates an infinite regress problem such that it would require that Mary be from a sinless line of humans - all the way back to Adam and Eve

@Mr.Bond Furthermore, John 14:4 reads: “You know the way to the place where I am going”

@RyanPierceWilliams Your just full of excuses aren't you? You mean a "Poetic" statement does not count as the truth? Romans 5:12 by the Apostle Paul is a flat out statement of truth. Then to top it off you made this foolish statement. "by your logic Christ could not be sinless since he was born to sinful man." Matthew 1:20, "do not be afraid to take Mary as your wife; for that which has been conceived in her is of the Holy Spirit." The one person of Jesus has two natures. Human on His mother's side and deity on His Father's side. Cont.

It's a universal law that a son shares the same nature as its father. You can prove me wrong on this by giving me an example of a son that does not share the same nature as its father.  The New Testament is replete with verses that Jesus Christ is the one and only begotten Son of God. Why do you think the Bible states that Jesus is sinless? God is not "biology" like the Mormons believe that God the Father had relations with Mary. Again, I rest my case.

@Mr.Bond it is a universal law that a child shares the same nature as its parents - not just the father. The two become one flesh. Scripture never isolates sin to the seed of man alone - as if women aren't carriers of sin. Nor is God a man that he can provide literal seed - Jesus' flesh comes from Mary.

Of course Jesus' flesh came from Mary, That's what I've been saying. So tell me where the deity of Jesus Christ came from? It comes from God Father. Why do you think that Jesus Christ is the one and only Son of God? John 3:16, what do you think only begotten means" as in there are no others? At the trial of Jesus the high priest ask the one person Jesus to swear as to His identity.  Tell us whether You are (1) the Christ/Messiah and (2) the Son of God. At Luke 22:70 Jesus said, Yes I am." "He has blasphemed. The Jews claim they are sons of God to, so how did Jesus blaspheme as the Son of God?

There’s only one God Almighty and Jesus is his Son - not Him. Or do you count Moses as part of the Trinity because God Almighty declares him to be such - with Aaron as his prophet? Or are the angels literally God because they speak as if God? At any rate an irrelevant question since by virtue of being man, born of sinful woman, then by your stated logic Jesus must be sinful

@Mr.Bond And - of course - Jesus is not sinful. It is merely your bad logic that moral responsibility for sin is inherited which produces the contradiction

Since your question is addressed to Christians, my answer will focus on believers who have come to saving faith in Christ Jesus and who have experienced the spiritual rebirth.
A New Testament example of a believer who acted out of character when under pressure is that of Peter, who was so afraid he denied his Lord and Saviour three times.  When he was identified as a follower of Jesus, he was afraid for his own safety and that made him weak. Weakness is born of human frailty, a condition we all suffer from.  Here is an extract from an article showing how Peter was overcome by fear:

Peter still followed Jesus after His arrest, but he kept his distance so as not to be identified with Him (Mark 14:54). There’s no question that fear gripped him. From the courtyard, he watched Jesus being falsely accused, beaten, and insulted (Mark 14:57–66). Peter was afraid Jesus would die, and he was fearful for his own life as well. The world hated Jesus, and Peter found that he was not prepared to face the ridicule and persecution that Jesus was suffering. Earlier, Jesus had warned His disciples as well as us today, “If the world hates you, keep in mind that it hated me first” (John 15:18; cf. Matthew 24:9). Peter quickly found he wasn’t nearly as bold and courageous as he had proclaimed, and in fear he denied the One who had loved him.
Source: https://www.gotquestions.org/Peters-denial.html

Prior to this event, Jesus had prayed for Peter, knowing what was to happen:

“I have pleaded in prayer for you, Simon, that your faith should not fail. So when you have repented and turned to me again, strengthen your brothers” (Luke 22:32, NLT). Peter’s leadership role in the early church proved that the Lord’s prayer for Peter was answered.


Jesus did not promise to remove Peter’s impending test. On the contrary, He predicted that Peter would fail the test by denying Christ three times (Luke 22:34). Trials are to be expected in the Christian life. “We must go through many hardships to enter the kingdom of God,” say the missionaries in Acts 14:22. God uses these experiences for our good (Romans 8:28), to refine our character and strengthen our faith (1 Peter 1:6–7; James 1:2–4,12), and to make us more like Jesus (Romans 8:29).


Before Peter’s threefold denial, he was overconfident, trusting in his own strength (Luke 22:33). But after being sifted like wheat, Peter learned that failure is possible because the flesh is weak (see Mark 14:38). Now that he understood how easy it is to fall, Peter would have compassion and mercy for others while helping them avoid the same mistake.


When Satan comes to sift us as wheat, we have an advocate, Jesus Christ, who intercedes for us (John 17:9, 11, 15). He will protect us so that the devil can never destroy our faith and hope (John 10:27–28; Hebrews 7:25). Jesus Christ began a good work in us, and He is faithful to complete it (Philippians 1:6).
Source: https://www.gotquestions.org/sift-you-as-wheat.html

Despite Peter’s failure, the resurrected Jesus forgave him, and he was restored.  Christians are held to account for their actions, but God forgives weak and imperfect Christians who repent and turn back to Him.

God knows our intent and motivation. He is all-knowing. So, we will be held accountable accordingly.
God is forgiving and therefore sincere repentance for such actions will lead to forgiveness.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

What Was I Thinkin (Dierks Bentley) really matters! There is quite a difference between murdering someone because you hate them and killing in wartime. Should America have stayed out of WWII? Does God never help countries in war?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTqra4YSsaM

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The old covenant was all about physical actions, not about mental attitudes. Bad thoughts didn't become a sin unless they were acted upon.
The new covenant expands sin to include thoughts and attitude.
E.g. Matthew 5:28:

Ye have heard that it was said by them of old time, Thou shalt not commit adultery:
But I say unto you, That whosoever looketh on a woman to lust after her hath committed adultery with her already in his heart.

One isn't judged by what one does, but by what one feels and thinks.
If one thinks or does something wrong, feels bad about it, realizes that one should not do such things, undoes any harm as much as is reasonably possible, and then as a result changes attitude and behaviour to avoid ever doing it again (repentance), then there is no longer any "accountability" for it.
There is no longer any purpose for guilt or punishment.
It is as if it never happened.
God doesn't care about what one did in the past, or even why.
He cares about what one wants to do now and will do in the future.
It happened and it will never happen again.
The experience has made a better person; that is all God wants.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
